# Disable ptrace on Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Is there a way to disable ptrace on debian.

I would like to see if there is something similar to what is done here for ubuntu: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/375990

Answer (score 0):

Try: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

Comment: Well, in my Debian 6 box there is no such directory yama.

Comment: It seems to be a kernel extension. What is the output of your `uname -a` ?

Comment: Linux roma 3.8.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed mar 20 22:10:25 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, with a huge plottwist:

According to [linux-audit.com](https://linux-audit.com/protect-ptrace-processes-kernel-yama-ptrace_scope/) -
For this [the yama/ptrace_scope] key there are four valid options: 0-3

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0: all processes can be debugged, as long as they have same uid. This is the classical way of how ptracing worked.
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 1: only a parent process can be debugged.
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 2: Only admin can use ptrace, as it required CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability.
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 3: No processes may be traced with ptrace. Once set, a reboot is needed to enable ptracing again.
```

=> value 0 enables ptrace for all processes instead of disabling it.

Note that this value, if changed e.g. to 2 or 3, is seemingly recovered to 0 upon a reboot. You will need to mangle with the boot flags or find another solution (that I have not yet found - will keep you updated in case I find something, as this touches critical security considerations on public machines)